# Regular expression to check for integer or decimal number in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring, nspredicate, nsregularexpression

I need to check whether the text is an integer or a decimal number.

I tried using the following:

```
NSString *expression =  @"\\d*";         
NSError *error ;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSTextCheckingResult *isValid = [regex firstMatchInString:txt options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [txt length])];
```

But the result is true even if the text is `2.14.256`.

Comment: If stringVal contains alphabets, [stringVal doubleValue] returns 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Yogesh: Thanks dude. but, this regex suits my needs.

```
- (BOOL)numberValidation:(NSString *)text {
    NSString *regex = @"^([0-9]*|[0-9]*[.][0-9]*)$";
    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    BOOL isValid = [test evaluateWithObject:text];
    return isValid;
}
```

This

Comment: If your answer helps you then, accept your answer so other users can use it. :)

Comment: This regex returns TRUE for a dot (.) too, which I think shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

use `NSPredicate` for checking Number validation with regex

```
- (BOOL)numberValidation:(NSstring *)text {
    NSString *regex = @"^([0-9]+)?$";
    NSPredicate *test = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    BOOL isValid = [test evaluateWithObject:text];
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: Even easier: `[text rangeOfString: regex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]`

Comment: This regex does not return TRUE for decimal numbers like 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (BOOL)isStringADecimalNumber:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *regex = @"(\[+\]|-)?((\[0-9\]+\[.\]?\[0-9\]*)|(\[0-9\]*\[.\]?\[0-9\]+))";

    NSPredicate *test = \[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex\];

    BOOL stringIsADecimalNumber = \[test evaluateWithObject:string\];

    return stringIsADecimalNumber;
}
```

Highlighted below, are the numbers that return **`TRUE`** for this regex:
[image]
[image]